# nagios servicedependency wildcard not expanding

Tags: monitoring, nagios

to reach customer-es-prd-dobb1, the packets must traverse a (client based) vpn via the host "cust-client-vpn". The intermediary host has a check named "customer-prod-vpn" which monitors the health of the particular connection.

The goal is to make the hosts services in the customers network all depend on a specific service on the intermediary machine. I however get

```
Error: Could not expand dependent services specified in service dependency (config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/conf.d/servicedependency/customer.cfg', starting on line 1)
Error processing object config files!
```

If I replace the wildcard with, for example, "cpu usage" (an existing check) it works.

Here's the related dependency block:

```
define servicedependency {
    dependent_host_name             customer-es-prd-dobb1
    dependent_service_description   *
    host_name                       cust-client-vpn
    service_description             customer-prod-vpn
    execution_failure_criteria      w,u,c
    notification_failure_criteria   w,u,c
}
```

The intermediary host config:

```
define host {
    host_name                       cust-client-vpn
    alias                           cust-client-vpn
    address                         ip_addr_was_here
    use                             nrpe-server,host-pnp
    hostgroups                      debian-servers, monit-servers
    _NRPESSL    -n
    contacts        operations
}
```

the intermediary host check which it all depends on

```
define service {
    use                             generic-service,srv-pnp
    host_name                       cust-client-vpn
    service_description             customer-prod-vpn
    check_command                   check_nrpe_1arg!check_customer_vpn_prod
    check_interval                  10
    max_check_attempts              1
}
```

And finally the status for "customer-prod-vpn" check in nagios:

```
customer-prod-vpn  OK   05-20-2013 16:21:15  0d 14h 50m 42s 1/1 OK - UP
```

Any nagios ninjas out there to point out what the problem is?

Comment: Try setting also setting wildcard for "service_description" in your servicedependency  definition.  I remember some odd issue where I had to set both of these to * to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'*' is only a valid wildcard when not using regex (use_regexp_matching=0). A wildcard in regex is at least .*

I went with .* and use_regexp_matching=1

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [time saving tips](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objecttricks.html#servicedependency) docs page... the description of using wildcards seems to indicate that your way **should** work, although they don't explicitly have an example of exactly what you're trying to do.

Given that your way isn't working, the only way I know of to do this is to use a service group.

Put all of the services on that host into a service group (perhaps using a template or a wildcard?), and use that servicegroup for the dependency. This *definitely* works; I do it this way.